# How can i enable syntax highlighting on "large" files in Komodo Edit?

Tags: configuration, syntax-highlighting, komodo, komodoedit

Komodo edit 8 disables syntax highlighting on large files for performance reasons. Is there anywhere to tweak the threshold, or disable the disabling completely?

My prefs.xml has:

```
<long id="documentByteCountThreshold">1000000</long>
<long id="documentLineCountThreshold">20000</long>
<long id="documentLineLengthThreshold">32000</long>
<boolean id="donotask_treat_large_documents_as_text">0</boolean>
```

My test file is 53520 characters (CP1252) over 1040 lines of PHP, and Komodo Edit refuses to syntax highlight it.

Answer (score 1):

Some time ago i've created following **javascript macro**. You need to add it to your **toolbox**

(i.e. go to toolbox, right click, New Macro... and make sure that JavaScript is marked as Language then paste the code )

**Macro code**:

```
var gprefs = Components.classes["@activestate.com/koPrefService;1"].
          getService(Components.interfaces.koIPrefService).prefs;

var bUserIsSure = confirm(
    'Current max file size: '+(Math.floor(gprefs.getLongPref("documentByteCountThreshold")/1024/1024*100)/100)+'mb and '+gprefs.getLongPref("documentLineCountThreshold")+' lines. Do you want to increase it 10 times?'
);

if( bUserIsSure ){
    (function(){

        var gprefs = Components.classes["@activestate.com/koPrefService;1"].
          getService(Components.interfaces.koIPrefService).prefs;
        gprefs.setLongPref("documentByteCountThreshold", 10 * gprefs.getLongPref("documentByteCountThreshold"));
        gprefs.setLongPref("documentLineCountThreshold", 10 * gprefs.getLongPref("documentLineCountThreshold"));
        // No reason to change "documentLineLengthThreshold"
    })();
}
```

Then execute it from toolbox as many times that you need or feel free to change multiply, for your own constants values.

Hope it will help.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following settings in [prefs.p.xml](http://community.activestate.com/faq/getting-setting-komodo-preference):

```
<!--
These prefs are to keep Komodo from hanging when a document
that hits at least one of these limits is loaded.  Komodo will
treat the document as a Text file, meaning all language-specific
functions, including code-colorizing, are dropped.
The reason for the high first value is that long lines are
costlier than long documents.  2013-11: Increase limits to
2MB / 40K lines / 100K max line-length due to fixing bug 101267
probably too low.
Also, Komodo estimates that colorizing UDL-based documents
takes about twice as long as languages with C++-based lexers,
and adjusts the limits by 50% downward.
-->
<long id="documentByteCountThreshold">2000000</long> <!-- 2 MB -->
<long id="documentLineCountThreshold">40000</long> <!-- 40K * 40c/line => 1.6 MB -->
<long id="documentLineLengthThreshold">100000</long><!-- 100K -->
<boolean id="donotask_treat_large_documents_as_text">0</boolean>
```

> Komodo stores preferences, macros, templates, keybinding schemes and other settings in a user-specific directory called the user data directory. The name and location of this directory varies depending on the operating system and Komodo version:

```
Windows Vista, Windows 7, Windows 8 or newer
C:\Users\<user>\AppData\Local\ActiveState\Komodo[IDE|Edit]\<version>

Windows XP or older
C:\Documents and Settings\<username>\Local Settings\Application Data\ActiveState\Komodo[IDE|Edit]\<version>

Linux
/home/<user>/.komodo[ide|edit]/<version>

Mac OS X
/Users/<user>/Library/Application Support/Komodo[IDE|Edit]/<version>
```

Restart Komodo to test the changes.

**References**

- [KomodoEdit repo: prefs.p.xml](https://github.com/Komodo/KomodoEdit/blob/master/src/prefs/prefs.p.xml)
- [Komodo File Locations: Where does Komodo Keep Settings Data?](http://community.activestate.com/faq/komodo-file-locations#appdata_dir)

Comment: Doesn't seem to make any difference for me

Comment: Yep (even rebooted since), but it didn't appear disable the disabling :(

Comment: added settings to question, along with metrics from my test file

Comment: tried with both, as the naming was unclear as to whether it is a flag to disable, or enable the feature...